# How to express $\mathbb{E}(X\,1\{Y>0\})$ in terms of the joint moments $\mathbb{E}(X^iY^j)$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$,$Y$ be real valued random variables. Assume that for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ we know $\mathbb{E}(X^iY^j)$. Is there a way to express $\mathbb{E}(X\,1\{Y>0\})$ in terms of these joint moments? ($1\{\cdot\}$ is the indicator function)

Is there any assumption about the distribution of X and Y that can simplify this problem?

EDIT: Assume also that $\mathbb{N}$ includes point zero.

EDIT (2nd):
So, I have a half idea which helps me make some progress, but there are multiple points of [extreme?] difficulty which compromise the whole thing.

Take the Heaviside function $H(x)$, where

$H(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\max(x,1)=\textbf{1}[x\geq 1]$

Therefore:

$\mathbb{E}[XH(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{d}{dY}\max(XY,X)]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{d}{dY}\min(-XY,-X)]$ (1)

Now, if we assume $X$ and $XY$ are bivariate normal, we have [1]:

$\mathbb{E}[\min(-XY,-X)]=\theta\,\phi\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]}{\theta}\right)-\mathbb{E}[XY]\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]}{\theta}\right)-\mathbb{E}[X]\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[XY]}{\theta}\right)$ (2)

where

$\theta = \sqrt{Var[X]-2Cov[X,XY]+Var[XY]}.$

Even with the above assumption, this is far from complete. I fail to be able to connect formula (1) and (2), since I cannot apply the Leibniz rule on a derivative involving a random variable.

[1] M. Cain, The moment-generating function of the minimum of bivariate normal random variables, The American Statistician, 1994

Comment: It may be helpful to know $E[X^iY^j]$ for cases when $i$ and/or $j$ can also be zero.  Roughly speaking, and neglecting (important) details related to convergence issues, you might obtain a joint distribution on $(X,Y)$ by an inverse transform of the characteristic function $$ f(u,v)=E[e^{iuX}e^{ivY}] = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!n!}E[(iuX)^m(ivY)^n] = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^{m+n}u^mv^n}{m!n!}E[X^mY^n]$$ which uses the expansion $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}z^n$.

Comment: Of course I am also assuming the known moments are finite.  A counter-example where  $E[X^mY^n]$ can be infinite and only known for $m\geq 1, n\geq 1$  is any positive random variable $X$ with finite mean but infinite second moment, with $X=Y$.  Then $E[X^mY^n]=\infty$ for all $m \geq  1, n\geq 1$ and knowing all of these are infinite gives you no information on the value of $E[X 1\{Y>0\}] =E[X]$.

Comment: Yes I should point out that I assumed $\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. I am still digesting the rest of yout answer, I will come back soon!

Comment: ((Please turn to informative titles. For an example, see the modified title above.))